# GTK how to use gtk_builder_add_from_string()

Tags: c, gtk, builder

I am new to Gtk and I am also using Glade to design a GUI.

What is the necessary steps to show a GUI designed in glade by using gtk_builder_add_from_string() ?

So far I loaded a .glade file into memory , ran g_type_init() and I got myself a gtk_builder_new() struct that I pass to gtk_builder_add_from_string().

What do I need to do next to show the GUI and "talk" with the widgets?

(sorry for a possibly stupid question but me and google are not exactly friends today)

Comment: For others with issues related to gtk_buildeR_add_from_string() I suggest reading this : http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Error-Reporting.html#glib-Error-Reporting.description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always thought this was a very good tutorial: https://web.archive.org/web/20151230154736/http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html

Answer (score 1):

In general the steps are the following:

1. Get the builder (you got it)
2. Call `gtk_builder_add_from_string`. That string has to be created in the .glade file. You just have to convert the file into a C string.
3. You can get the different graphical elements using `gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"name")`, where name is the name of some element. You usually have a top-level window in it.
4. Call the `show()` method on all the widgets you recover from the builder. In particular, the top-level windows.

This will bring your application to life. Note that you also can connect signals and such. You can see an example [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#h6QnRr6SU3A/trunk/src/main.c&q=gtk_builder_add_from_string%20lang%3ac&sa=N&cd=5&ct=rc).